# Equations homogeneous in $X$ and $y$

Tags: terminology, definition, dimensional-analysis, scaling

Arfken and Weber in their mathematical methods for physicists edition 6 on page 334 talk about equations homogeneous in $X$ and $y$ and tells they are homogeneous if the combined powers of $X$ and $y$ add to $n$ in all terms of $P(X,y)$ and $Q(X,y)$ what this statement means?

Comment: It's a *definition* it does not have to *mean* anything beyond what it says.  Such functions have some useful properties, however, which is why the definition is made.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add some significant information. The most common rationale behind the consideration of homogeneous functions is that you want them to have definite scaling properties. Consider, e.g.,
$$
f\left(x,y\right)=ax^{3}+bx^{2}y+cxy^{2}+dy^{3}+e\frac{x^{4}}{y}
$$
This function satisfies the definition of homogeneous in $x$ and $y$. Now let's see what happens when I rescale the variables:
$$
f\left(\varLambda x,\varLambda y\right)=\varLambda^{3}f\left(x,y\right)
$$
Voila! The function scales in a definite way. Now, I don't need to say how important this is, not only in physics, but also in the theory of complex systems, biology, and so on.

Comment: IMO the most useful answer so far in terms of physics.

Answer (score 3):

This definition simply means that if you have some polynomial, for example
$$ P(x, y) = x^3 y^4 + x y^6 + x^5 y^2 + y^7 $$
you can check whether it is homogeneous by adding the exponents in each of the terms together, and see if they are all the same. In this example,
$$ P(x, y) = \underbrace{x^3 y^4}_{3+4=7} + \underbrace{x y^6}_{1+6=7} + \underbrace{x^5 y^2}_{5+2=7} + \underbrace{y^7}_{0+7=7} $$
they all add up to $n = 7$. If one of the sums were not equal to 7, it would not be a homogeneous polynomial, for example
$$ Q(x, y) = x^2 y^4 + x y^3 + x^5 y^2 + y^7 $$

Answer (score 0):

An equation $f(x,y)$ of degree $n$ is said to be homogeneous if it can be expressed as $$f(x,y)=x^n g(\frac{y}{x})$$.

Ex: $$f(x,y)=x^2y+y^2x$$
Then, $$f(x,y)=x^3[\frac{y}{x}+(\frac{y}{x})^2]$$

Here $n=3$ and $g(\frac{y}{x})$ is $[\frac{y}{x}+(\frac{y}{x})^2]$